# Race condition between Monitor.Pulse and Monitor.Wait?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, race-condition

Here is a minimal code that illustrates the issue:

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

void ToUpper()
{
    lock (input)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(input);

            Console.WriteLine(input.ToString().ToUpper());
        }
    }
}

public void Run()
{
    new Thread(ToUpper) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

    // "Avoid" the initial race
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    while (true) 
    {
        lock (input)
        {
            input.Clear();
            input.Append(Console.ReadLine());
            Monitor.Pulse(input);
        }
        // Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Ignoring the well-known initial race-condition, I'm surprised by the behavior of Pulse and Wait.

Here is what I expected:

- the "ToUpper" thread calls `Wait` => it is pushed into the monitor's waiting queue
- the main thread calls `Pulse` => the "ToUpper" thread is "moved" from the waiting queue to the ready queue for immediate acquisition of the lock
- the main thread exits the monitor when exiting the `lock` statement scope
- the "ToUpper" thread acquires the lock and processes input while the main thread is registering again for ownership of the lock

But **one time out of two the "ToUpper" thread does not process the input and instead the main thread executes its processing immediately**.

Here are  with my assumptions:

- `Pulse` does not "move" the "ToUpper" thread immediately so the ready queue stays empty
- the main thread releases the lock, loops, requires the lock again
- as there is nobody else in the ready queue it takes ownership
- sometimes later the request for promoting the "ToUpper" thread is executed and it is finally pushed into the ready queue
- the main thread `Pulse` a second time for nothing and releases the lock
- it loops, tries to reacquire the lock but the "ToUpper" thread is already there
- this time the "ToUpper" thread acquires the lock and process the input
- once done it sleeps again waiting for the next signal
- the main thread acquires the lock

To check this assumption I've forced the main thread to be less eager and to let the other thread work, by adding the `Thread.Sleep(1)` => in this case all is "working as expected".

So it all boils down to the behavior of `Pulse` that might not push immediately the threads from the waiting queue to the ready queue.

**Does the issue really comes from this possible race or is there another subtlety I'm missing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remark about adding `Thread.Sleep(1)` is really the answer. The [`Pulse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) method doesn't guarantee anything for the waiting object - it is just released to the [ready queue](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) from which it proceeds as an ordinary thread. There is no trace anywhere about the call to the `Pulse`. Thus, after you call `Pulse` the application behaves as ordinary two-threaded application, and there are two threads in the ready queue - the `ToUpper` thread **and** the `Run` thread. So without `Thread.Sleep(1)` it can happen (without it it's also possible I guess, just less probable) that the `Run` thread obtains the lock first.

Another important remark from the second link I've provided:

> An important feature of Monitor.Pulse is that it executes asynchronously, meaning that it doesn't itself block or pause in any way.

For this scenario the [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) class seems more suitable. Also, in the [second link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) you can find an example of a producer-consumer scenario with `Wait` and `Pulse`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bartosz. The MSDN documentation is not really clear, it could mean that the thread is moved immediately, which is apparently not the case. In your second link there is no such issue because the two operations, pushing and popping from the collection, never overlap, whereas in my situation the second thread depends on state that is overridden by the first one. I've tried to disassemble the Monitor class but it forwards to extern functions ObjWait/ObjPulse. Your quote confirms my assumptions.

Comment: From the same article: "Further, when a notifier pulses and releases its lock, there’s no guarantee that an eligible waiter will kick into life immediately. There can be a small delay, at the discretion of the thread scheduler, during which time neither thread has a lock. This means that the pulser cannot know if or when a waiter resumes — unless you code something specifically (for instance with another flag and another reciprocal, Wait and Pulse)." and "Relying on timely action from a waiter with no custom acknowledgement mechanism counts as “messing” with Wait and Pulse. You’ll lose!"

Comment: @Pragmateek Yes indeed, I've found the whole article quite interesting. So also thanks for your question, which led me to finding it :)